# Close a series of views in a for-loop [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, loops, uiview, uikit

I need to close a series of views and don't wont to write code for closing them one by one. Here's a sample code to illustrate what I mean:

//This is the method for placing the views. It's called at different times at runtime:

```
- (void)addNotePic:(int)number {

int indexNumber = ((110*number) + 10);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Note.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
[image release];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, indexNumber, 300, 100);
imageView.tag = 100 + number;
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack: imageView];
[imageView release];
```

}

//And heres the issue-part, and the thing I'm asking you guys about. This is the method that I wish to remove all the displayed views at once.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    UIView *imageView = [self.view viewWithTag:100 + i];
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I know this results in errors, since I try to redefine imageView the second time it loops, but how can I work around this. Might be something to rename the name 'imageView' to 'imageView + i' or something more clever. Would love a good suggestion...

Comment: Your issue isn't with the variable `imageView` being redefined, that's perfectly legal. Do you get an error message in the console? Have you stepped through this in the debugger? Is it doing what you think it is? What line is the error coming from? Are there definitely views with the tags 100..119?

Comment: -1. Variables don't work like that. Your code is fine.

Comment: Console message is: Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. Checked it up, and it was bad memory management. Solved the whole problem by not releasing the view after creation. Not the best way, but it solves it for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit I am taking a quick guess, but would this work?

```
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:100 + i] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Think I tried that last night, but it didn't seem to target the views correctly. I'll try again when I come home...

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove *all* UIImageViews from self.view.  Note that the mutable array is necessary as you cannot modify an array that is being iterated over ( as in the for loop)

```
NSMutableArray *removeThese = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
 if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
  // [view removeFromSuperview]; <-- This will result in a runtime error
  [removeThese addObject:view];
 }
}

[removeThese makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```